# Accessing Module variables/methods across multiple project files

Tags: vb.net, variables, methods, module

I am working on a system that is using Modules in its base project file. As new projects are created, the variables/methods referenced in the Module of the base project file need to be available to the new projects. What is the best practice here? I have never worked with Modules before and all of the reading I am doing to starting to spin my head.

Here is a stripped down version of what I am trying to accomplish. If I need to build a whole new method and move all of the items out of the module and into some form of a class structure that is available to any and all existing/new project files then so be it. I can go back and update the existing code base to reference the new class structure.

```
MainProjectFile.vb (this is a snapshot of the existing Module)
    Module mdlMain
        Friend userID as integer
        Friend key as integer
        Friend tabCounter as integer
        ...
        ...
    End Module


NewProjectFile.vb
    public class createNewTab
         public sub new()
              'need to access tabCounter in the module back in the main project file
               mdlMain.tabCounter =+ 1
         end sub
    end class
```

Comment: You might have reference issue. If you do, than your module should be in it's own project and reference the ModuleProject into all the other project of your solution. Better yet, put all these variable in it's proper place. UserID should be inside a LogUser class, the TabCounter should be inside the CreateNewTab class.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the access level of a module as well as its methods using the keywords Public, Private, Protected, Friend [(see MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx). If your example code were in the same project, you should already have the access you need (the friend modifier means that all code in the same project can access the tabCounter variable).

If you prefix your Module with Public, then that module can be accessed by pretty much anyone, even code that is defined in a separate project (using a reference to the project containing your module).

If you're coming from another language, you can think of a module as nothing more than a class where all of its members are declared as static (Shared in the VB term) and a private constructor that limits you to using it as a singleton.

This code:

```
Public Module Module1
   Public Sub SampleMethod()
      'Do something interesting here
   End Sub
End Module
```

Can be translated to:

```
Public Class Module1
   Private Sub New()
   End Sub

   Public Shared Sub SampleMethod()
      'Do something even more interesting here
   End Sub
End Class
```

There's a bit more happening under the covers. A module lets you access members without fully qualifying them. A class, on the other hand, requires that you at least specify the class name.

```
'Using your code example
public class createNewTab
     public sub new()
          'need to access tabCounter in the module back in the main project file
           mdlMain.tabCounter =+ 1
          'no need to use the module name unless there's another module with the same member
           tabCounter = 42
     end sub
end class
```